# How can I force scrapy-splash to retry failed items?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm using scrapy-splash to extract information from Javascript-driven IFRAMEd HTML pages. Sometimes, my splash Javascript function fails due to some browser condition and returns an error message like `{"error": "NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9"}`).

In my Item pipeline I drop these items in order to keep my results clean:

```
class NewspaperLayoutPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item.has_key('error'):
            raise DropItem("Error capturing item %s" % item)
            ...
```

Unfortunately, my error item rate is about 40%. So I'd like to have scrapy-splash retry these failed urls instead of simply dropping the items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retry an item in Pipeline.

You should write a check in your Spider and then `yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)` the same URL again

```
def parse(self, response):
    if item.has_key('error'):
        raise DropItem("Error capturing item %s" % item)
        yield Request(response.url, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: thanks! Two remarks: I am using a SplashRequest which doesn't have the dont_filter argument. Also, I'd like to set a maximum number of retries to avoid endless loops.

Comment: It has bro. Do a simple Google search and you will see it.